# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'detail' is undefined

Tags: flask

I have passed details.html in my route but still got this error

I have passed details.html in my route but still got this error

I was expecting the contents of details.html but got this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3tRF.png)

```
 from flask import Flask,render_template,request
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

 app = Flask(__name__)

 app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://root:@localhost/practice'

 db=SQLAlchemy(app)
 @app.route("/detail")
 def detail():
      return render_template('detail.html')
 app.run(debug=True)
```

```
**detail.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<body>
 
   <div class="class1">


   <h1>Hello World</h1>
   <p>Welcome to part 2 of my Jinja2 Tutorial. In part 1 we learned what Jinja2 is, 
    what are its uses, and we started looking at templating basics. Coming up next are 
    loops and conditionals, sprinkled with tests and a healthy dose of examples!</p>
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a [jinja2.exceptiones.UndefinedError](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.UndefinedError) is raised when you are trying to operate (in this case a variable) [that is undefined](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Undefined).

Since your `detail.html` doesn't have any reference to a `detail` variable is likely that your `base.html` does.

For example if you are just trying to use an undefined variable, it shouldn't have problems. If your template had this line: `<p>Detail: {{ detail }}</p>`, it would simply render like `<p>Detail: </p>` but if you try to acess a variable like `<p>Detail: {{ detail.msg }}</p>` it will raise an exception `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'detail' is undefined`

### Ways to fix this

For a template that his this line `<p>Detail: {{ detail.msg }}</p>`

1. Pass a `detail` variable as a named argument to `render_template`

   ```py
   # The structure/type of `detail` will depend on how you use it in your template.
   @app.route("/detail")
   def detail():
       return render_template('detail.html', detail={"msg": "Hello, World!"})
   ```
2. Check in your jinja2 template whether `detail` is defined or not before doing anything. You can do this with an if statement inside the template.

   ```html
   {% if detail is defined %}
   <p>Detail: {{ detail.msg }}</p>
   {% endif %}
   ```
3. Check your `base.html` if `detail` is needed, if it isn't just remove the variable as it looks like you aren't aware of such variable.